# CSV with multiple headers. How to maintain reference header-row

Tags: python, csv, header

I have a **csv file** that looks like this:

```
row ID  A B C D E ""  "" ""
row 0   1 1 1 1 1 ""  "" ""
row ID  E F B G D  H   I  L
row 0   1 1 1 1 1  1   1  1 
row ID  A B C M "" "" "" ""
row 0   1 1 1 1
```

Basically, I have an element in row ID to which is associated the number 1 and the same element may be repeated over several lines.
What I would like to get is this:

```
A B C D E F G H I L M
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Namely, I would like to put all row ID on the first line (without repetitions) and associate to all elements **a number 0 or 1** based on the associations in the first table.

In order to put all the elements on the first line I have looked at this question [Read CSV with multiple Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23165147/read-csv-with-multiple-headers) but the result I get is not what I want. I get everything in one line:

```
row ID  A B C D E ""  "" "" row 0   1 1 1 1 1 ""  "" ""  row ID  E F B G D  H   I  L  row 0   1 1 1 1 1  1   1  1
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: This is the actual csv file http://www.sharecsv.com/s/020ac800b8f194494fd21a7a79ad9499/df.csv

Comment: does the header same in all the rows?

Comment: @deadshot sorry, I'm not sure I understood, but this is my csv file (ignore the index column) http://www.sharecsv.com/s/020ac800b8f194494fd21a7a79ad9499/df.csv

Comment: just read it as a normal file and create new file by filtering the headers

Comment: @deadshot yep, that is what I am trying to do..I will keep going then, hope I'll manage!